# AJAX equivalent for Android Java

Tags: java, android, jquery, ajax

I am currently working on an application for android. My background is web development and I have been using ajax to update information on the screen from a server without reloading the page. I was wondering (and maybe many others as well) what is the equivalent to ajax for android?

The goal is to have the contents of an activity updated or changed with the same asynchronous flow as ajax. Examples of the usage would be things like a messenger or an list updated from a database.

I know this is a newbie question but I hope this might also help others.

**Update I am using Volley for server communication**

Comment: AJAX automation in updating part of a page is based on the fact that the page and its part is something standardized i.e. HTML markup. Android activity contents is not that standard. One cannot build a "working-for-all" automation here.

Answer (score 0):

I think AsynkTask with notifydataSetChange in recycler view adapter will be helpful.
Another way is to create a service and call notifydataSetChange if the existing json not equal to the json already at the app.